# Where is the place of the classes and packages in Android?

Tags: java, android

I worked in `C++` already. For example, all the libraries of the `C++` ware in a specified folder with the the name of the libraries.

I know that the libraries in Android are in the `SDK` folder. But, when I search in the `SDK` folder I can't find the `packages` name and the `classes` name. While there are many packages and classes in android to use. Where are the packages and the classes in the `SDK` folder?

For example in `C++` if we want to use the `#include <iostream>` as the result we must have the `iostream.cpp` file in the `IDE`. But in Android studio and in the `SDK` folder I can't find the packages name and the classes.

If the packages and the classes aren't in the `SDK` file, then how can we use them in the Android?

Comment: I don´t know which answer you would except? the whole sdk is build up with packages containing either packages and/or classes in different jar files

Comment: Are you looking for the `android.jar` file in the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Java runtime and all the android packages are installed on each device, so you don`t have to package them with your application (obviously).

Then java developer kit and android SDK's is installed on your dev machine, so that you are able to compile as well as other things, these are installed where you selected them to be installed.
The `JDK` is downloaded and installed from the java website.
The `Android SDK's` are installed via the `SDK manager` within `Android Studio`.

Im not sure if that clears things up for you.